# CasperJS timeout while logging into a bank account

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm attempting to login to a Capital One 360 bank account using CasperJS. It loads the username screen, properly enters a username, loads the password screen, but then times-out (presumably, there's no error) and stops after entering the password.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

var capone360 = "https://secure.capitalone360.com/myaccount/banking/login.vm";

casper.start(capone360);

casper.then(function(){
   casper.waitForSelector("#ACNID", function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.sendKeys('#ACNID', username);
    }, true); 
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.click("#btn_continue"); 
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.waitForSelector("#currentPassword_TLNPI", function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.sendKeys('#currentPassword_TLNPI', password);
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.clickLabel("Continue", "a");
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.waitForSelector("#deposittable", function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    }, true);
});

casper.run();
```

PhantomJS version 2.0.0

**Update**
Switched to PhantomJS 1.9.8. per @Artjom B. suggestion. Now there are errors saying:
'Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: xpath selector: //a[text()="Continue"]'.

It's attempting to click:

```
<a class="ada-new-win" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" onclick="submitForm('continue'); return false;">Continue</a>
```

I assumed it should be there given that it's waited for the password input box to load, but am I forgetting something else?

Comment: Yes. I installed the latest version yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 2.0.0 has a bug where errors are not printed to the console even when specifically listening to the various error events. That is why you don't see the obvious error which would go something like this:

> TypeError: true is not a function

The reason for that error is that you're providing `true` as a third parameter for `waitForSelector()`, but the function signature is

```
waitForSelector(String selector[, Function then, Function onTimeout, Number timeout])
```

It seems that some step in your script breaks, because a selector cannot be found. The passed function for `onTimeout` will be executed, but `true` is not a function. Simply remove the third parameter to see where the error lies. If still nothing is shown, try using PhantomJS 1.9.8.

---

You either need to wait for the "Continue" button to appear using `waitForSelector(x(selector))` and/or you need to use a more robust selector:

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
...
var continueButtonSelector = x("//a[contains(text(), 'Continue')]");
casper.waitForSelector(continueButtonSelector);
casper.thenClick(continueButtonSelector);
```

This is sometimes necessary, because the element is probably defined with whitespace like this

```
<a>   Continue   </a>
   ^^^        ^^^
```

which means that `text()="Continue"` cannot match. The browser renderer disregards this whitespace, but it is still in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, but removing true doesn't change anything. It just hangs and then the program ends.

Comment: As I said, try to use PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Comment: I added a guess why you have the issue.

Comment: The whitespace is probably the issue. If I look closer at the html, there's a HUGE amount of whitespace after "Continue". In the meantime, I've got it working by calling the function that the click calls directly.